# How can i extract month and year from a string in python?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, datetime, nlp

Input **text**:

```
text = "Wipro Limited | Hyderabad, IN                Dec 2017 – Present
Project Analyst 

Infosys | Delhi, IN                Apr 2017 – Nov 2017 
Software Developer 

HCL Technologies | Hyderabad, IN                Jun 2016 – Mar 2017 
Software Engineer  
"
```

I have written a code for this but it displays in list for each extracted word and unable to do anything of it.

```
regex = re.compile('(?P<month>[a-zA-Z]+)\s+(?P<year>\d{4})\s+\–\s+(?P<month1>[a-zA-Z]+)\s+(?P<year1>\d{4})')
mat = re.findall(regex, text)
mat
```

Check out the code : https://regex101.com/r/mMlgYp/1.
I want the output like below to preview the dates and make difference of it then calculate total experience:
Here Present or Till date should consider current month and year.

```
import time
Present = time.strftime("%m-%Y")
Present 
# output: '05-2020'
```

```
#Desired output
Extracted dates: 
[('Dec 2017 - Present'),
 ('Apr 2017 - Nov 2017'),
 ('Jun 2016 - Mar 2017')]# and so on ...should display all the search results 

First experience: 1.9 years 
second experience: 8 months
third experience: 7 months
# and so on ...should display all the search results 
Total experience: 3.4 years
```

Please help me with this I'm new to programming lang and NLP, regex stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably ultimately want this in a dataframe since you tagged it pandas (see [Andrej's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62110244/6243352)), but either way, you can parse dates from the string with the interpolated:

```
fr"(?i)((?:{months}) *\d{{4}}) *(?:-|–) *(present|(?:{months}) *\d{{4}})"
```

Where `{months}` is an alternating group of all possible month names and abbreviations.

```
import calendar
import re
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

text = """Wipro Limited | Hyderabad, IN                Dec 2017 – Present
Project Analyst 

Infosys | Delhi, IN                Apr 2017 – Nov 2017 
Software Developer 

HCL Technologies | Hyderabad, IN                Jun 2016 – Mar 2017 
Software Engineer  
"""

def parse_date(x, fmts=("%b %Y", "%B %Y")):
    for fmt in fmts:
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(x, fmt)
        except ValueError:
            pass

months = "|".join(calendar.month_abbr[1:] + calendar.month_name[1:])
pattern = fr"(?i)((?:{months}) *\d{{4}}) *(?:-|–) *(present|(?:{months}) *\d{{4}})"
total_experience = None

for start, end in re.findall(pattern, text):
    if end.lower() == "present":
        today = datetime.today()
        end = f"{calendar.month_abbr[today.month]} {today.year}"

    duration = relativedelta(parse_date(end), parse_date(start))

    if total_experience:
        total_experience += duration
    else: 
        total_experience = duration

    print(f"{start}-{end} ({duration.years} years, {duration.months} months)")

if total_experience:
    print(f"total experience:  {total_experience.years} years, {total_experience.months} months")
else:
    print("couldn't parse text")
```

Output:

```
Dec 2017-May 2020 (2 years, 5 months)
Apr 2017-Nov 2017 (0 years, 7 months)
Jun 2016-Mar 2017 (0 years, 9 months)
total experience:  3 years, 9 months
```

Comment: Hi @ggorlen, Thanks a lot for quick response.It is perfectly working for the above code but when I was parse a resume into text and passing this text file into the above code, it is throwing an error. https://ibb.co/w42sQ6m. (image attached). Error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'years'. Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: Can you post the text in `s`? The likely cause is that the resume string is different from the one shown here causing the regex to fail, so `re.findall` returned no results and `total_experience` never got set.

Comment: @ggorlen, please find the attached image. https://ibb.co/9p36RHG

Comment: Please post it [as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). I can't copy and paste this or see whitespace, etc. Nonetheless, it's pretty clear that the addition of the `^(.+?) *\| *(.+?) *` which works well on your original format won't work on this version. If you remove that along with anything related to `company` and `location`, it should work.

Comment: Here is the text: PROFESSIONAL EXPERIENCE
June 2007 – Till date
Noble Group/Clear Capital, Mumbai
highlighting key growth drivers, and identifying top sector picks.

 Authored five initiation reports, with name duly accorded on their front page.
 Involved with  forensic examination  of financial statements of accident management and vehicle rental emphasis on their operating and financial leverage.

Irevna Research Services (subsidiary of S&P), Chennai
Oct 2005 – May 2007
Offshore  equity   research   associate  responsible   for   fundamental   research   of   European   Household

Comment: Sorry, that's pretty much useless... Post a link to the actual plain text string on a text file hosting site.

Comment: Apologies. Can you rewrite the code for only dates extraction and calculating. that would really help me a lot.

Comment: If you don't mind can you please suggest best resource to start regex and nlp stuff. I'm really new to this and want to learn it. Apologies for troubling.

Comment: All right, thanks. See my update. Keep in mind that regex can't parse arbitrarily-formatted text, so it's a bit hard (impossible?) to code something that can extract date ranges from a bunch of random pdfs. They have to be fairly well-formed and it can be an endless task trying to write in all of the edge cases (two-digit years instead of four-digit years, `'05` instead of `2005`, different whitespace and delimiters...).

Comment: It works awesome. Thanks a lot. :) :) :) :) :)  If possible can you share some of resources regarding regex, so that I can learn by myself and be a good coder.

Comment: Sorry for troubling, When i added into function. it is throwing an error . URL: https://pasteboard.co/JaRNaO4.png  ValueError: time data 'June 2007' does not match format '%b %Y'. It is the same text used.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215009/discussion-between-jirekol432-and-ggorlen).

Answer (score 3):

```
import re
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

text = '''Wipro Limited | Hyderabad, IN                Dec 2017 – Present
Project Analyst

Infosys | Delhi, IN                Apr 2017 – Nov 2017
Software Developer

HCL Technologies | Hyderabad, IN                Jun 2016 – Mar 2017
Software Engineer
'''

def pretty_format(monthts):
    return f'{monthts/12:.1f} years' if monthts > 11 else f'{monthts:.1f} months'

data = []
for employer, d1, d2 in re.findall(r'(.*?)\s*\|.*([A-Z][a-z]{2} [12]\d{3}) – (?:([A-Z][a-z]{2} [12]\d{3})|Present)', text):
    data.append({'Employer': employer, 'Begin': d1, 'End': d2 or np.nan})

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Begin'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Begin'])
df['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End'])

df['Experience'] = ((df['End'].fillna(pd.to_datetime('now')) - df['Begin']) / np.timedelta64(1, 'M')).apply(pretty_format)
print(df)

total = np.sum(df['End'].fillna(pd.to_datetime('now')) - df['Begin']) / np.timedelta64(1, 'M')
print()
print(f'Total experience = {pretty_format(total)}')
```

Prints:

```
           Employer      Begin        End  Experience
0     Wipro Limited 2017-12-01        NaT   2.5 years
1           Infosys 2017-04-01 2017-11-01  7.0 months
2  HCL Technologies 2016-06-01 2017-03-01  9.0 months

Total experience = 3.8 years
```

Comment: OP got 3.4 years, you got 3.8 years and I got 3.9 years. *dies*

Comment: @ggorlen I think it's something with rounding, when I use `.2f` in my formatting, I get `3.83 years`. _dies too_

Comment: Oh wait, I got 3 years and 9 months which isn't the same as the decimals. I feel like fractions of a year are weird so I'm going to stick with the month format.

Comment: Hi @Andrej Kesely, Thanks a lot for quick response. Thanks for applying dataframe which is needed in later stages. It is perfectly working fine for the above code but when I was parse a resume into text and passing text file into the above code, it is throwing an error. https://ibb.co/FwyQRmS. (image attached). Error: KeyError: 'Begin'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: